# Null values in json_encode with a generated PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, null, json

I've been looking over the **simple html dom** for PHP and it works very well. The problem is when I try to add the returned values to a PHP array.

I have an example where you can see the result http://fae.ctrl.fo/plane_script/ and the script below is what gives the data from that link.

```
<?PHP

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$resultSet = array();
$html = file_get_html('http://212.55.50.147');
foreach($html->find('tr[class^=FlightScheduleItem]') as $tr)
    {
        $row = array();
        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td) 
        {
            echo $td->innertext." ";
            $row[] = $td->innertext; 
        }
        $resultSet[] = $row;
    }

    echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($resultSet) . ')';
?>
```

As you can see I'm printing all the values I find in the **td** tag and I'm saving them in an array in the same loop. If you check the output you'll see that "**Reykjavík**" is not found in the array.

Do you have any idea why?

**later edit:**

If I use the print_r function from PHP I can find the word in my array. This means that **json_encode** transforms *Reykjavík to null*.

Do you know why or an alternative?

Thanks

**later edit:**

Thanks to your help I modified this line:

```
$row[] = htmlentities($td->innertext, UTF-8);
```

... and now it works.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's something to do with the encoding. It's `Reykjavík`, not `Reykjavik`. Note the special character `í`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `json_encode` expects UTF-8 input, but the default on PHP is ISO-8859-1.

You should be able to do this:

```
$resultSet[] = htmlentities($row, UTF-8)
```

This should encode the latin character as UTF-8, allowing it to be passed through (encoded) in the `json_encode` function.

Solution found on [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49588)

Comment: I've got `Notice: Use of undefined constant UTF - assumed 'UTF'` ; I think that PHP is seeing `UTF-8` as "UTF" minus 8